# Can't Install netbeans on Mac OS 10.7

Tags: macos, netbeans, java, osx-lion

Just got a brand new mac.

However when I try to install netbeans 7.0.1, I get to the part of the installation where it wants me to select a destination to install. But it says "Netbeans 7.0.1 cannot be installed on this disk. This software can be installed and work only with Java 6."

I have installed the new 10.7 JDK from apples developer website here:

http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.10.3.3.1

But I am still getting the message.

What am I missing here.

Comment: Maybe you need to install Java, if I remember correctly, all versions of Java were uninstalled when you installed Lion

Comment: Well now I feel stupid. I guess I just assumed that apple would have pre-installed java.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot to install java developer tools.  The Java Developer Tools are available from the Apple developer downloads site, or Oracle.

OSX lion does not come with java developer toolkit pre-installed.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Worse, I could not install the system JVM after installing the developer preview. After some digging, it seems the developer preview creates a broken symbolic link to CurrentJDK. To fix:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
rm CurrentJDK
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_27-b07-395.jdk/Contents/Home CurrentJDK
```

This is partially the Netbeans installer's fault as well. It hasn't been updated yet to the newer JDK path style that Apple introduced a while ago (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines).

Comment: Is JDK needed for installing Netbeans, or is should JRE be sufficient?

Comment: I think we need JDK, as Netbeans will use it for compiling our java source code. Thanks for this neat tips. It works!

Answer (score 2):

Tnx allot [@jsravn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274614/jsravn) for your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180900/cant-install-netbeans-on-mac-os-10-7/7809783#7809783). Still i wanted to add more info because I'm still on Snow leopard (latest is 10.6.8) but encountered this same problem.

Although Netbeans uses the default installer, their installation uses `unpack200` a Java Command. This was causing the fatal error. I found this when looking at /var/log/install.log:

```
   [truncated]
   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/bin/unpack200: No such file or directory
```

**The Solution** is to symlink CurrentJDK to the newer JDK. (similar to @jsravn)

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
mv CurrentJDK CurrentJDK_old
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_27-b07-395.jdk/Contents CurrentJDK
```

*But as you can read the error log the symlink should end in Contents*

I believe this is introduced by the "Java 6 update" by Apple software updates. target versions are Mac OSX 10.6.* or greater

**Note that it is odd that Apple did not update the symlink themselves. It may be wise to restore the CurrentJDK symlink afterwards.**

Answer (score 0):

There are related posts on that subject in StackOverflow and, as I'm facing the same issue, I guess that Netbeans is not finding JDK on your system (as well as on mine...)

As mentioned by many people JDK is no more part of OS X Lion, but has to be installed and there are 2 versions: one from developer site and one that is uploaded by "Mac update" when needed.

I had no trouble using Netbeans with the second one as it does not install in the same directories.